# cURL cannot resolve address Instagram API

Tags: php, json, api, curl, instagram-api

EDIT: turns out it was all because of proxy server.
I using internet over a proxy server and curl was not set up to use proxy server
i had to add these lines to my php code

```
 $proxy = '192.168.100.13:8080';
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
```

if you want to use proxy when using curl with terminal use

```
curl --proxy 192.168.100.13:8080 google.com
```

Hey guys this is my first time using an api, I am trying to get information from instagram api and am stuck.
I am trying to connect with instagram api to get user info
CURL gives me cannot resolve error.
The link works fine if i run it in my browser, it shows the json.
I have tried this code with other URLs too but same result.
I want to extract JSON from the url.

my php code is :

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$_h = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1); 
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN' ); 
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false ); 
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2 ); 
echo '<br>';echo '<br>';

var_dump(curl_exec($_h)); echo '<br>';echo '<br>';

var_dump(curl_getinfo($_h)); echo '<br>';echo '<br>';
var_dump(curl_error($_h)); 


?>
```

On running this i get

```
bool(false) 

array(26) 
{ 
["url"]=> string(102) "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN" 
["content_type"]=> NULL 
["http_code"]=> int(0) 
["header_size"]=> int(0) 
["request_size"]=> int(0) 
["filetime"]=> int(-1) 
["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) 
["redirect_count"]=> int(0) 
["total_time"]=> float(0) 
["namelookup_time"]=> float(0) 
["connect_time"]=> float(0) 
["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) 
["size_upload"]=> float(0) 
["size_download"]=> float(0) 
["speed_download"]=> float(0) 
["speed_upload"]=> float(0) 
["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) 
["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) 
["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) 
["redirect_time"]=> float(0) 
["redirect_url"]=> string(0) 
"" ["primary_ip"]=> string(0) "" 
   ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } 
   ["primary_port"]=> int(0) 
   ["local_ip"]=> string(0) "" 
   ["local_port"]=> int(0) } 

string(41) "Couldn't resolve host 'api.instagram.com'"
```

I have also tried using `get_file_contents();`

the code i used is

```
$result = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN')
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

this gives error

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
```

I have set allow_url_fopen=1 in my php.ini file

Any help on what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you able to ping it from the server?

Comment: I am doing it on localhost and the url is accessible from my browser and i can see the JSON when i open the link in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just try it with a little help by composer instagram api:
https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

maybe you will benefit from it: